# Which CRC algorithm must be used to query the Tamper Tag status from a NTag213?

Tags: nfc, crc16, ntag21x

I'm trying to read the "TT status" of a Tamper Tag NTag 213 (using a TWN4 reader).

The "Read TT status" command is A4 00 + CRC ([documentation](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT2H1311TT.pdf)).

I seem to have a problem with the CRC calculation, as the command always returns 01. 01 is documented as "NAK for parity or CRC error".

Could you tell me which algorithm I should use to calculate the CRC?
I've tried the CRC_A algorithm, which gives D63F for the given payload (A400).
Is this CRC value wrong?

Comment: It was an error with the CRC_A byte order (little endian).

Answer (score 0):

Normally most NFC reader hardware does the CRC calculation for you.

As the datasheet of the Tag outlines what it's hardware expects at the ISO 14443-3 level, but what you send to the reader is actually an instruction asking it to generate the desired 14443-3 command.

Thus you only send to the reader hardware the instruction `A4 00` (usually with USB readers this is wrapped in an APDU command).

Comment: It is a type-2 tag. So it relies on Mifare Ultralight instead of ISO7816. I think that ISO14443-3 is the only way to send a custom command.

Comment: Yes ISO14443-3 is the only way to send data to the Tag, but most USB readers work on ISO7816 commands (I could not find any technical detail on your particular USB reader). So usually you are not directly talking to the Tag but asking the USB reader to talk to the Tag and thus have to tell the USB reader via a APDU to send ISO14443-3 data. So the reader receives the APDU that tells it to send the APDU payload via ISO14443-3 to the Tag.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, the CRC is [CRC-16/ISO-IEC-14443-3-A](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-iso-iec-14443-3-a), which has these parameters:

```
width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0xc6c6 refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0000 check=0xbf05 residue=0x0000 name="CRC-16/ISO-IEC-14443-3-A"
```